# Embedded youtube videos in Safari/ WKWebview requires long press to resume playing

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, wkwebview

In my web content, there is an embedded Youtube video (in an iframe rendered by utilizing Youtube's API). When the video is loaded upon navigating to the page, the video plays without problem upon tapping on it.

However, after I quitted from full screen and paused the video, long press on the video is required in order to resume playing (or through clicking the play button in the controls if they are displayed by setting the *controls* flag), tapping on the video will not have any response.

I tried the load the same page with Safari and the behaviour remains the same. Is there anyway to enable to resume playing the video through tapping?

Comment: I also have the same problem. @alanlo - did you find a workaround for this?